# serializeToJSON não envia variaveis para o php

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho um loop While no meu php que contém  para pegar variaveis através de POST com o plugin **serializeToJSON**.

Ele funciona em parte, porém ele sempre pega o último resultado do loop do PHP com os inputs, quando deveria pegar todos os inputs do loop, por exemplo

Tenho esse loop

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="id_i" id="id_i" value="<?php echo $id_i; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="id_usuario" id="id_usuario" value="<?php echo $id_usuario; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="auxiliar_fornecedor" id="auxiliar_fornecedor" value="<?php echo $produto["auxiliar"]; ?>">   

<div class="number" data-last="<?php echo substr($produto ["telefone"], 6, 6); ?>"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>  <?php echo substr($produto ["telefone"], 0, 6); ?><span><strong>Clique aqui para ver o número</strong></span></div>

</form>
```

O javascript sempre pegará o último registro do loop 
Como eu poderia fazer para que cada vez que clicasse na div class="number" do loop php enviasse todos as variaveis para o arquivo php "meu_ajax.php"?

Comment: Código java Script

$('.number').click(function(ev) {
 $(this).find('span').text( $(this).data('last') );
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url:'meu_ajax.php',
              data: $("form").serialize(),
              error: function () {
                alert('Erro');
              }
          });
      });

Comment: Poderia mostrar a parte que usou o serializeToJSON?

Comment: $('.number').click(function(ev) {
 $(this).find('span').text( $(this).data('last') );
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url:'meu_ajax.php',
              data: $("form").serialize(),
              error: function () {
                alert('Erro');
              }
          });
      });

Comment: Mas o plugin que você citou?